# React Native - TextInput focus while onClick Text Label won't work

Tags: javascript, react-native, focus, textinput, ref

I just want to make textinput focus easier for more user-friendly application. I try to do when user miss click textinput and click text instead it should focus to textinput.

So I added ref to text as

```
  <Text ref={"textref"}
```

and on TextInput

```
 <TextInput onPress={_onPress => { this.refs.textref.focus() }}
```

It worked for 1 word label texts but It didn't worked for long texts. What can I do?

Also it says refs is deprecated is there better way to do it? I find this way shortest and effective but sadly it is deprecated.

Edit: I fixed it.

```
<Text onPress={() => {this.inputText.focus()}} 
<TextInput ref={input => { this.inputText= input}}
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're trying to focus a Text, but you can focus only TextInput

Then, i suggest you to init your ref in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    ...

    this.textInputref = React.createRef()
}
```

And

```
<Text onPress={() => this.textInputref.current.focus()}>hello world</Text>

<TextInput ref={this.textInputref} />
```

Comment: I think I need a rest lol. Now I changed as you said but it gives error as this2.textref.focus is not a function

Comment: try this.textInputref.current.focus()

Comment: I just found the fix in another question. I did <Text onPress={() => {this.textInput.focus()}}  and <TextInput ref={input => { this.textInput= input}}   it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use is simply like this:

```
<Text onPress={_onPress => { this.refs.textref.focus() }}> Testing </Text>
<TextInput ref={"textref"}/>
```

Comment: I use it like that but it says refs is deprecated. I found the solution this worked for me.
  <Text onPress={() => {this.input.focus()}}>Click Me</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} ref={input => { this.input = input}}/>